# RequireJS - custom paths and the text! plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-text

I'm working on a SPA, and have optimized one of my code files with the requireJS optimizer, and set the new path like this:

```
config.paths['billingmanager/billing/billing'] = 'billingmanager/billing/billing-build';
```

Unfortunately, code that now (conceptually) does this

```
require(['text!billingmanager/billing/billing.htm'], callback);
```

now attempts to find `billingmanager/billing/billing-build.htm` and fails miserably.

Can can I tell text! that, no matter how the normal require path for `billingmanager/billing/billing` is set, I want you to fetch the file `billingmanager/billing/billing.htm`—period.

I do have a workaround, to do something like this

```
config.paths['billingmanager/billing-htm'] = 'billingmanager/billing/billing.htm';
```

and then manually know to use `require(['text!billingmanager/billing-htm']);` but I'm really hoping there's a simple fix here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not run into this specific problem but the first thing I'd do to work around it would be to replace the path I give to `text!` with a relative path, which should avoid the clash with the path you've got in your `paths`. So, for instance:

```
require(['text!../parent/billingmanager/billing/billing.htm'], callback);
```

Of course the actual relative path you should use depends on the architecture of your application. It turns out that just using `./` won't be enough to work around RequireJS' cleverness so in the illustration above, I'm backing out of the current directory and then going back in. I've assumed that the current directory is name `parent`.

Note that the rules for path resolution for the path given to `text!` is *different* than the regular path resolution rules. Normally, adding an extension to a path given to `require` will completely bypass the `paths` setting. So `require(['billingmanager/billing/billing/foo.js']...` will look for a file named `billingmanager/billing/billing/foo.js` relative to `baseUrl` and will not use the `paths` setting you've shown in the question. **This is not the case for paths given to `text!`.** These paths go through the `paths` setting even if they have an extension. (This is documented [here](https://github.com/requirejs/text#usage).)